# Evaluate Tensor in Graph Mode

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

The title already says it: I need to evaluate a tensor in graph mode (to access a value in a dict by string name). Unfortunately, this raises an error.

Is there a workaround?

```
@tf.function
def any_function(a):
    return a.numpy().tolist()

b = tf.constant(2)
any_function(b)
```

raises:
"AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'"